# Correct intent flags to use

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Within my Main Activity that loads a Webview, depending on where it was launched from determines the url to load.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras != null) {
           String theurl =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
            webView.loadUrl(theurl);    
       } else {
             webView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");
       }
```

If the application is a fresh instance and loaded from the home screen it loads the default url.

If the application is not running and i click a notification that was sent through google cloud messaging the application loads a custom url.

This functions as expected.

My problem lies when the application is already running in the background, when i click a notification it will bring the app to the front but wont load the new url, it stays at the default.

I'm not too sure with the Flags, i did have this problem before and it was a certain combination of flags that fixed it.

```
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("url", url);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT*

If i add the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT   this almost solves the issue, although it reloads the whole main activity (Splash screen gets called), i want it to reuse the existing webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the flag you're looking for:  FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to
>   be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity
>   becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old
>   activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

**EDIT:**
If you place your webview code in onResume and then don't use any flags, it should work fine.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion. this reloads the whole activity (Splash screen). I would like it to reuse the existing webview and simply change url.

Comment: Hmm i removed all flags and moved the webview although it's still not working, i'm pretty sure as well my solution last time was somethin similar but i can't remember having to move the whole webview to the onresume. Most likely a stupid mistake on my part, its 3am so i'll sleep on it and attack it again in the morning.

Comment: @Guernica ok, it should be working though so tomorrow, if you could post your updated code, I can take a look at it

Comment: Yeah i'll post my code in the morning, the problem seems to be that when inside onresume the extra data being passed via the intent (the url ) is missing.

Comment: I seem to have got it working, you were right about the onresume although i still had to set a flag, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP   and also had to override the intents   @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent);
     setIntent(intent);
 }

Comment: Your help was much appreciated.

Comment: I have one other minor issue if you can help.   i need to save the instance state on pause, if the application is in the background and i resume as normal from running the app again (not from the notification intent) it reloads the last intent with the get extras thus reloading the custom url.

Comment: Glad I could help, a little confused what do you want to save? The URL?

Comment: yeah i need to save the current url or just the application state when the application loses focus and restore it onresume.

Comment: I believe what you do is you add it to your bundle in on pause the same way that you retrieve from the bundle. Not sure though

Comment: yeah i've tried a couple of methods with varying degrees of success, not completely nailed it. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: Might be a bit late. But you could use/ could've used SharedPreferences for this. Just make sure you keep it updated.